# Create a role to view cluster events

Tags: kubernetes

I created a cluster role to view its events:

```
kubectl create clusterrole events-view -n my-namespace --verb get --resource events
kubectl create clusterrolebinding events-view -n my-namespace --group 'activedirectory_group://my-groups-canonical-name' --clusterrole events-view
```

But when I try to see events I get this:

```
> kubectl auth can-i get events -n my-namespace
yes
> kubectl get events -n my-namespace
Error from server (Forbidden): events is forbidden: User "u-wwrp76jtem" cannot list resource "events" in API group "" in the namespace "my-namespace"
```

This is the output of `kubectl version`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.8", GitCommit:"ec6eb119b81be488b030e849b9e64fda4caaf33c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T21:00:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.4", GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-03-12T20:55:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the user `u-wwrp76jtem` is part of the group `activedirectory_group://my-groups-canonical-name`

You should try below command to verify the groups permission

```
kubectl auth can-i get events -n my-namespace --as-group=activedirectory_group://my-groups-canonical-name
```

Comment: I'm a member of this group, so I figured I could use the generated kubernetes user as if it was my AD account